# R's split&apply&combine routine in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have been long time R user and slowly shifting to Python.

I have some split&apply&combine routine in R but I have a difficulty to find python equivalent of these functions like `grepl`, `paste`, `select` etc.
What I am trying to do is in step by step

1. read files with the extension .txt in the folder
2. Delete the rows with 'TRIAL' string
3. select some particular columns and name this columns
4. make sequence of groups in a new column 'No' when the 2.nd column value 0.1 reappear again
5. multiply this second column with 2 and make a new column
6. add file name as a new column for each file

and finally make a data.frame output.

```
         tt      m1      m2      m3      m4      m5      m6  No  tt2 file_name
1       0.10 -0.0047 -0.0168 -0.9938 -0.0087 -0.0105 -0.9709   1  0.2   sum_W_1
2       0.20 -0.0121  0.0002 -0.9898 -0.0364 -0.0027 -0.9925   1  0.4   sum_W_1
3       0.30  0.0193 -0.0068 -0.9884  0.0040  0.0139 -0.9782   1  0.6   sum_W_1
4       0.40 -0.0157  0.0183 -0.9879 -0.0315 -0.0311 -0.9908   1  0.8   sum_W_1
5       0.50 -0.0402  0.0300 -0.9832 -0.0093  0.0269 -0.9781   1  1.0   sum_W_1
```

here is the example [file][2]

head(sum_data)

```
TRIAL :            1        3331        9091
  TRIAL :            2  1384786531   278055555
    2     0.10     0.000E+00 -0.0047 -0.0168 -0.9938    -0.0087 -0.0105 -0.9709     0.0035  0.0079 -0.9754     0.0081  0.0023  0.9997      -0.135324E-09    0.278754E-01
    2     0.20     0.000E+00 -0.0121  0.0002 -0.9898    -0.0364 -0.0027 -0.9925    -0.0242 -0.0050 -0.9929     0.0029 -0.0023  0.9998      -0.133521E-09    0.425567E-01
    2     0.30     0.000E+00  0.0193 -0.0068 -0.9884     0.0040  0.0139 -0.9782    -0.0158  0.0150 -0.9814     0.0054 -0.0008  0.9997      -0.134103E-09    0.255356E-01
    2     0.40     0.000E+00 -0.0157  0.0183 -0.9879    -0.0315 -0.0311 -0.9908    -0.0314 -0.0160 -0.9929     0.0040  0.0010  0.9998      -0.134819E-09    0.257300E-01
    2     0.50     0.000E+00 -0.0402  0.0300 -0.9832    -0.0093  0.0269 -0.9781    -0.0326  0.0247 -0.9802     0.0044 -0.0010  0.9997      -0.131515E-09    0.440350E-01
```

What I have tried,

```
import os
import glob # damla, topak
import pandas as pd
import numpy

filelist=glob.glob('*.txt')
print(filelist)

names_cols=['tt','m1','m2','m3','m4','m5','m6','m7']

for file in filelist:
    df=pd.read_table(file, header=None,skiprows=7,skipfooter=0,names=names_cols,usecols=[1,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
    df_del=df[df.V1.str.contains('TRIAL')==False]
    concatdf=pd.concat(df_del,axis=0)
```

CParserError: Too many columns specified: expected 7 and found 1

Even this simple stage I stuck!

please help to finish this script!

Comment: Instead of posting the R code - which many of us don't know how to read, can you explain what are you trying to achieve with a sample dataset and the desired output?

Comment: @ayhan sure. please check the OP. I revised it!

Comment: Try adding `sep='\s+'` to the parameters in your `read_table()` command. By default, it assumes that the columns are tab-separated, but your file looks like it just uses white space to separate columns.

Comment: @Craig thanks man! What about deleting the rows start with `TRIAL` but seems that it turned to be `:` in for example row 499

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following translation. And because R's `lapply` saves dataframes to a list you will need to do the counterpart in Python appending dataframes to an initialized list:

```
names_cols = ['tt','m1','m2','m3','m4','m5','m6','m7']
v1 = ["W_1","B_1"]

dfs = []
for file in filelist:
    df = pd.read_table(file, header=None, skiprows=7, skipfooter=0, sep="\s+",
                       names=names_cols, usecols=[1,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])

    df = df[~df['tt'].str.contains('TRIAL|:')]        # KEEP ROWS WITHOUT TRIAL AND COLON
    df['tt'] = df['tt'].astype(float)                 # CONVERT TO FLOAT COLUMN
    df['tt2'] = df['m2'] * 2                          # MULTIPLY BY 2 (DOES NOT CHANGE SIGN)
    df['No'] = (df['tt'].cumsum()==0.1).astype(int)   # BOOLEAN OF A SERIES CUMSUM()        
    df['file_name'] = file[0:3]+'_'+ v1[0]            # EXTRACT FIRST THREE LETTERS
    dfs.append(df)                                    # APPEND TO LIST

print(dfs[0].head())
#     tt      m1      m2      m3      m4      m5      m6      m7     tt2  No file_name
# 0  0.6 -0.9872  0.0119 -0.0119 -0.9883  0.0306 -0.0259 -0.9903  0.0238   0   Spl_W_1
# 1  0.7 -0.9877 -0.0382 -0.0227 -0.9803 -0.0293 -0.0252 -0.9864 -0.0764   0   Spl_W_1
# 2  0.8 -0.9859 -0.0256  0.0218 -0.9829 -0.0323 -0.0098 -0.9870 -0.0512   0   Spl_W_1
# 3  0.9 -0.9838 -0.0030 -0.0032 -0.9844  0.0048 -0.0206 -0.9866 -0.0060   0   Spl_W_1
# 4  1.0 -0.9885 -0.0346 -0.0061 -0.9865 -0.0259 -0.0105 -0.9887 -0.0692   0   Spl_W_1
```

And for shorter lines, pandas' [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) can best serve as counterpart to R dplyr's `mutate` with multiple column assignment but do be aware multiple assigned columns are ordered alphabetically:

```
for file in filelist:
    df = pd.read_table(file, header=None, skiprows=7, skipfooter=0, sep="\s+",
                       names=names_cols, usecols=[1,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])

    df = df[~df['tt'].str.contains('TRIAL|:')].assign(tt2 = df['m2'] * 2, file_name = file[0:3]+'_'+ v1[0])
    df = df.assign(tt = df['tt'].astype(float), No = (df['tt'].astype(float).cumsum()==0.1).astype(int))
    dfs.append(df)
```

*By the  way, why slowly shift from R to Python? Use both awesome languages!*

Comment: thanks man for your elegant answer. This is what I was looking for ! You are right they are both great languages. I feel that wiring python code is little bit tedious than R.

Comment: I have one more comment. Can we do `df['tt']`,`df['tt2']` and `df['No']` operation in a one line of code like R's `dplyr` ? Someting like `mutate(tt=as.numaric(as.character(tt)), tt2=m2*2,No=cumsum(tt==0.1))`

Comment: Consider `assign` to add multiple columns in one call. See edit.